# How to show that $\mathcal{K}/\mathcal{O}$ is isomorphic to$\sum_{P\in X} i_P(I_P)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This a Hartshorne exercise (Ex II 1.21d)
Let $X=\mathbb{P}^1$. Let $\mathcal{K}$ be the constant sheaf of the quotient field of X. Then we need to show that
 $\mathcal{K}/\mathcal{O}$ is isomorphic to the direct sum of sheaves: $\sum_{P\in X} i_P(I_P)$, where $I_P=K/\mathcal{O}_P$, and $i_P(I_P)$ is the skyscraper sheaf at point $P\in X$.

I would like to check the stalks.
If Q is a closed point of X, then $(\mathcal{K}/\mathcal{O})_Q=K/\mathcal{O}_Q$, and $(\sum_{P\in X} i_P(I_P))_Q=I_Q=K/\mathcal{O}_Q$.

My problem is their stalks at the generic point $\eta\in X$.

$(\mathcal{K}/\mathcal{O})_\eta=0$, since $\mathcal{O}_\eta=K$.

How about $(\sum_{P\in X} i_P(I_P))_\eta =\sum_{P\in X} i_P(I_P)_\eta=\sum_{P\in X} I_P = \sum_{P\in X} K/\mathcal{O}_P$

Is the last direct sum equal to zero? or I made any mistakes?

Thanks

Comment: In fact $i_P(I_P)_\eta=0$ because $i_P(I_P)$ is supported on $P$.

Comment: oh, yea, I was wrong,  $i_P$ is support on $ \bar{P}$ the closure of point P. But I got a wrong way, I thought every closed point is in the closure of the generic point $\eta$. But I need consider the closure of point P. Thanks~ It is a naive mistake.~

Comment: As for the exercise, note that it is not enough to just check the stalks : you need a map between the two sheaves.

Comment: The inclusion $i_P: {P} \rightarrow X$ induces a morphism for each point P. then all of them give a morphism from the direct sum, due the universal property of direct sum?

Comment: Well, if I warned you, it is because you really need to say something. You cannot replace $\mathcal{O}$ by any other sheaf. In fact, the inclusion $P\rightarrow X$ induced the restriction $\mathcal{K}/\mathcal{O}\rightarrow i_P(I_P)$, not the other way around.